# Outlook 2007 Sent Sub Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have created sub folders under Sent Mail. In the sub folders it does not show who they were sent to when I open the sub folder. It shows only that I sent them which I know of course. 
Is there a way to make it show who they were sent to just as it does when they are in the main sent folder?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You have to enable the field "To" from the "Field Chooser".

To access the "Field Chooser", right click the messages grid header and select "Field Chooser" option from the drop down menu.

Finally, drag the "To" column from the "Field Chooser" to the header.

Comment: This goes for any folder that isn't the "Sent Items" itself. +1 for you.